# Update another table row in Azure Mobile Services Javascript

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have two tables in Azure Mobile Services (javascript backend): TableA and TableB. I want to update a specific row in TableB everytime a read query runs in TableA. Both tables have the same column "Date" used to identify which row to update.

I'm trying to accomplish that through the following code (added to the read script in TableA), which is not working to update TableB (it works to update TableA, if I change table name in var myTable to TableA)

```
function read(query, user, request) {

request.execute({ success: function(results)
{
request.respond();
//retrieve TableB reference
var myTable = tables.getTable('TableB');
myTable.where({   
   //retrieve TableB specific row by date
   Date: results[0].Date 
}).read({
    success: function(results){
        //reference row to be updated in TableB
        var tableRef = results[0];
        tableRef.Views = tableRef.Views + 1;
        //update row in TableB
        myTable.update(tableRef);        
    }});}});}
```

Please, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**, the following code works:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    request.execute( { success: function(results) {
        request.respond();
             var countTable = tables.getTable('TableB');
             countTable.where({date: results[0].Date}).read({
                success:  updateCount                 
                });

                function updateCount(results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                // tracking record was found. update and continue normal execution.
                var trackingRecord = results[0];
                trackingRecord.views = trackingRecord.views + 1;
            countTable.update(trackingRecord);
            } else {
                console.log('error updating count');
                }
        }
    }
});};
```